# How to learn ideals and quotient rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, ideals

I have difficulties to learn ideals of ring and how to operate with them. Is there somewhere a good tutorial on those? Like I saw from an algebra book the Artin–Rees lemma and it looked a bit scary as one had to raise ideals to some power and take an intersection of ideal times module with module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA58AC5CABC1321A3

This course was taught using the Artin book so i think this one is the best one to follow

Dr. Gross explanation is very good you may need to pause and rewind and digest some material at times but i am sure these lectures bring great clarity.